# How to search "My apps" on Google Play or show a text listing?

Tags: google-play-store, adb

I have quite a number of Android devices.  Not all of them have the same apps.  On Google Play, it shows a `My Apps` section that shows a picture with the name of the apps in what appears a random order. I'm not sure how many, but it's quite a few pages where I have to keep clicking "more" to see more of them. It takes me a very long time to find a particular app on the list.

Google Play on the Android (phones and tablets) have a menu item called `Library` which allows you to see your `My Apps`. I can scroll down the huge list that includes pictures, but it takes a very long time to find the app I'm looking for.  Sometimes, I get to the bottom and have to start over because I miss it on the list. The Google Play app has a search feature, but it doesn't search just "My Apps", it searches all the apps on Google.

If there is a way to get a text listing of "My Apps", it would be easy to find the app that I'm looking for. The most ideal method would be an `adb shell` command to list the **My Apps Library**. By the way, the **My Apps Library** is a list of the apps on all your devices, not just the individual device you're currently using. One of the purposes of trying to search the list is so that I can better manage the redundant and obsolete apps in my library.

My question is, how to search the list rather than having to scroll down the list?

Comment: Well there's this: https://9to5google.com/2017/02/03/google-testing-redesign-my-apps-section-google-play-sort-option/

Comment: @AndroidDev Thanks for prompt the input!  The link shows an image of what I tried to describe that shows in the updated androids for the libraries and installed applications.  It doesn't show, or describe a method of actually searching the **My Apps" only, just scrolling through them.  Are you provide the link as a suggestion for me to post the question to that community in their comment section?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. Have not found a better solution then:

1. List all the apps on the Google Play's My Apps website (with repeated clicking show more)
2. Selected all site content with Ctrl + A
3. Copied it
4. Pasted into a text document
5. Search for the keyword there

Comment: Thanks for the input, but I believe you are describing the problem that I expressed in my question.  Over the years I have accumulated more apps that I actually can count.  I believe every time you install an app, the number increases... while I don't think uninstalling the app decreases the number.  So with there being so many apps, I kind of give up after so many of the clicks that you describe.  With the question unanswered, someone might discover a method to eliminate the many clicks, or the actually flaw might eventually get fixed.

Answer (score 1):

The apps are listed under My Apps in an order of *Date first acquired*. The app which you most recently acquired is listed on the top.

I was/am in a similar situation wherein I was looking for an app from my library. The app is called *Flamingo* and it was unlisted from the store. That means, it won't come up in the full search on the Play Store, but the app is downloadable if I open the direct Play Store URL or open it from My Apps.

I spent hours scrolling through the list of apps and finally found it. So, long story short, Google Play gives us no way of searching through the My Apps list.

**Partial solution:**

Google Play store on Android now allows us to sort the *Library - Not on this device*  in an Alphabetical Order. This makes it much easier to scroll through and reach the app, provided we know the initials of the app's name.

[image]

Still, no go when you only remember a partial name and want to do some hit and trial.

Answer (score 0):

I believe to search apps under 'Installed' or 'Library' lists just *can't* be done currently. The option is just not available.

When one tries to search an app, I believe it is safe to assume one will know the name of the app they want to search. If this is the case (knowing the app name), you have an interim solution, which is to use the sort options available in both the above lists (Installed & Library). If one chose the sort option to list apps in those list to an 'alphabetical option', then one could just quickly scroll to the alphabet the app they want to search for in the quickest time.

Until Google wakes up to this missing feature, this is as good as it gets.